Migrate users from Sitecore 9.0.2 to ASP.NET Core Identity
We are migrating away from Sitecore to another CMS.
We would like to migrate all the users and their profiles to the new system.
I believe that Sitecore (9.0.2.) uses IdentityServer3 and our new system uses ASP.NET Core Identity which is essentially IdentityServer4 I believe.
How to migrate the users from the old system to the new one?
Can the passwords remain the same?
Any help will be appriciated

Just to clarify, are you asking about migrating your Sitecore users to another CMS or migrating them from one Sitecore instance to a higher version of Sitecore? There are multiple ways if you are migrating from one sitecore instance to another but if you want to migrate it to another CMS I guess custom scripts would be the best possible solution.

Migrating to another CMS, but I believe both use IdentityServer, just different versions.
